# Ultrapowers by extenders of potential premice

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I have a problem with an argument in Fine structure and iteration  trees by Mitchell and Steel. Let $E$ be a $(\kappa, \lambda)$-extender. Let $\dot E^{\mathcal{M}}$ the a unary predicate with is interpreted as the extender sequence at $\alpha$. Let $\dot F^{\mathcal{M}}$ be a 3-ary predicate interpreted as the weakly amenable coding of $E_{\alpha}$.

Mitchell and Steel define the ultrapower in the case $\mathcal{M}$ is active. In the first page in<sup>1</sup> https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnl/1235423433 there is case 1 where $\mu < \kappa$ ($\mu$ is the critical point of  $\dot F^{\mathcal{M}}$).

The authors claim this directly implies that $g$ is constant almost everywhere ($g$ is defined a couple of line before the argument). I don't understand why that is so. Thanks for any help.

<sup>1</sup>Chapter 4: Ultrapowers (by William J. Mitchell, John R. Steel); Lecture Notes in Logic, 1994: 34-46 (1994) (in the book Fine Structure and Iteration Tree)

Comment: FSIT?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Fine Structure and Iteration Trees, [MS] 1994

Comment: You want to put a proper citation, not everyone reading this will be aware of that.

Comment: OK, I am editing this right now. Actually, looking a second time at it, I think I've got the answer I'm looking for. The above thing is true just by definition of an equivalence class in the ultrapower. If $\mu$ is less than $\kappa$ then nothing is moved by the embedding at the level of $\mu$

Comment: If you have an answer you can post it as an answer to your own question. Give it a day or two for some feedback, and then accept it if you are certain it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ E $ is an extender on the sequence of some premouse $\mathcal{N}$ such that $ \mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{N}|lh(E)}(\kappa) = \mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{N}}(\kappa) = \mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{M}}(\kappa),$ where $crit(E) = \kappa$.

1. If $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are premice and  $ \mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{N}}(\kappa) = \mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{M}}(\kappa)$, then $\kappa^{+\mathcal{M}} = \kappa^{+ \mathcal{N}} =: \theta $ and $ \mathcal{M}|\theta = \mathcal{N}|\theta$.

This implies the following:

2. $\pi^{\mathcal{M}}_{E}(\kappa) = \pi^{\mathcal{N}}_{E}(\kappa)$,  $\pi^{\mathcal{M}}_{E}(\kappa^{+}) = \pi^{\mathcal{N}}_{E}(\kappa^{+})$ and $Ult_{0}(\mathcal{M},E)|\pi^{\mathcal{M}}_{E}(\kappa^{+}) = Ult_{0}(\mathcal{N},E)|\pi^{\mathcal{N}}_{E}(\kappa^{+})$

We also have from the coherence of $E$ and the fact that $\kappa$ is a cardinal in $\mathcal{N}$ that

3. $ Ult_{0}(\mathcal{N},E)|\pi^{\mathcal{N}}_{E}(\kappa) \models \kappa \ \text{is a cardinal}$

Thus by 2. we have

4. $ Ult_{0}(\mathcal{M},E)|\pi^{\mathcal{M}}_{E}(\kappa) \models \kappa \ \text{is a cardinal}.$

Since $Ult_{0}(\mathcal{M},E) \models \pi(\kappa) \ \text{is a cardinal} $, it follows from 4. and acceptability that

5. $Ult_{0}(\mathcal{M},E) \models \ \kappa \ \text{is a cardinal}$

From 5. and the fact that $\mathcal{M} \models (\kappa \ \text{is a regular caridnal} )$ it follows that

6. $\mathcal{M} \models \ \kappa \ \text{is a inaccessible cardinal}$

We have $Ult(\mathcal{M},E) \models h:\pi^{\mathcal{M}}_{E}(\mu) \rightarrow \bigcup_{n\in\omega}\mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{M}}([\pi^{\mathcal{M}}_{E}(\mu)]^{n}) $ and $h=[b,g]_{E}^{\mathcal{M}}$, by Los, we can assume that $g:\kappa^{|b|} \longrightarrow \bigcup_{n\in\omega}\mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{M}}([\mu]^{n})^{\mu}$. We are in the case $ \mu < \kappa$ so from 6. we have

> $\mathcal{M} \models |\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{M}}([\mu]^{n})|^{\mu} < \kappa $

So we can assume that $g$ is constant a.e. $E_{b}$.